# Import node_modules from non relative location

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, tsc, .d.ts

I'm trying to import a custom made framework that I have pushed to npmjs.org. Im building a .js file and a .d.ts file.

When actually importing I get no errors until I compile. All the map links work and point to the source when ctrl+clicking on them etc and the types file seems to be picked up.

What happens when I compile is any file importing any of these modules tries to import it relative to its own path. I have gone through a bunch of question on stack already and tried many of the suggestions. I have tried using paths in the tsconfig which doesnt seem to work.

Error:

```
ERROR in ./src/scripts/game/mGameModel.ts 17:16-34

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'Scratch' in '/Users/derek/Projects/ghg/cash-mania/src/scripts/game'
```

The actual library files are located at;

`node_modules/@myorg/game-framework/dist/Scratch.js`
`node_modules/@myorg/game-framework/dist/Scratch.d.ts`
`node_modules/@myorg/game-framework/dist/Scratch.js.map`

Am I building the types file incorrectly maybe or what could I possibly be doing wrong.

Here is my tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/phaser/types",
      "./node_modules/@myorg/game-framework/dist/",

    ],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "types": [
      "node",
      "phaser",
    ],
    "paths": {
      "Scratch": [
        "./node_modules/@myorg/game-framework/dist/Scratch"
      ]
    },
    "lib": ["dom", "es5", "esnext"]
  },
  "include": [
    "node_modules/phaser3-rex-plugins-types",
    "node_modules/@myorg/game-framework/dist",
  ],
}
```

So I have tried adding the paths, and Ive tried that multiple ways using `Scratch/` and `Scratch/*` as I saw in other answers for similar questions.

I also tried adding the folder into the include and made sure to set baseUrl to `./` but no matter what I do it always seems to try to import my Scratch Module from the directory of the file importing it.

Here is my webpack file

```
const path = require('path')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const PACKAGE = require('./../package.json');
const version = PACKAGE.version;
const name = PACKAGE.name;

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./src/scripts/Index.ts'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
    modules: ["node_modules", 'src']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { 
        test: /\.tsx?$/, 
        include: path.join(__dirname, '../src'), 
        loader: 'ts-loader'
      },
      { 
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'string-replace-loader',
        options: {
          search: '${WEBPACK_VERSION}',
          replace: version,
        }
      }
    ]
    
    
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        commons: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendors',
          chunks: 'all',
          filename: '[name].bundle.js'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ gameName: name, template: 'src/index.html' }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: 'src/assets', to: 'assets' },
      ],
    })
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it may not be exactly what you are looking for but here is how I use path import with '@'

1 - install these babel dependencies, it will help you compile the paths:

```
npm install -D @babel/cli @babel/node @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-typescript babel-plugin-module-resolver babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata
```

2 - create a file called babel.config.js, in it you will create custom paths...

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: '14.19.13'  // NODE VERSION COMPILE
        }
      }
    ],
    '@babel/preset-typescript'
  ],
  plugins: [
    ['module-resolver', {
      alias: {
        '@domain': './src/domain',  // HERE <<<<<<< 
      }
    }],
    'babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata',
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }]
  ],
  ignore: [
    '**/*.spec.ts',
    '**/*.test.ts',
    'test/**/*.spec.ts'
  ]
}
```

3 - in your ts.config.json, in the parameter "path" seven also how you want to import...

```
"paths":{
    "@main/*": ["main/*"],
}
```

4 - in your script create one for build like this...

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src --extensions \".js,.ts\" --out-dir dist --copy-files --no-copy-ignored"
}
```

here is a project of mine in case you want to base yourself on it:
https://github.com/Christiangsn/Nodejs-API-IntegrationWithFacebook/blob/Master/package.json

bonus: if you want an alternative to nodemon use:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths

Comment: This wasn't what i was looking for, But I did manage to get it working by rebuilding it as multiple files commonjs module instead of amd as one file. Still trying to figure out why it wont work with just 1 js file. Upvoted for the suggestion though